# How can R.head be of type 'chain a'

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to understand [buzzdecafe's Chain chain chain article](https://buzzdecafe.github.io/2016/12/29/chain-chain-chain)

That article explains how one can append the first value in an array to the (end) of that array with R.chain, and why that works.

```
const f = chain(append, head); //=> f :: [x] -> [x]`
f([1, 2, 3]); //=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

In the fifth last paragraph he writes that

> head is of type m a

As someone who have just started to experiment with functional programming I don't get that.

I don't fully understand the substitution that goes on in the article from different types of chains from array to function and vice versa.

The type of R.chain is:

```
(a -> m b)          ->  m a       ->  m b
```

I understand that a chain *can be* a function. So R.append that has the type `x → [x] → [x]` can be rewritten as `a -> m b` and that fits the first part of the R.chain type. I assume that means that we've now defined (or whatever the word is) `m b` to be `[x] -> [x]` so that the last `m b` also **must** be replaced with `[x] -> [x]`?

In that case what we have would look like this:

```
(a -> [x] -> [x])   ->  m a       ->  ([x] -> [x])
```

And since a and x will be of the same type (in this case number) we have:

```
(x -> [x] -> [x])   ->  m x       ->  ([x] -> [x])
```

So the first past matches R.append. The end matches the type the returned function. Great, I sort of understand it I think...

But... that `m x` in between how does that fit R.head? `m x` can be a function that returns something of type x? Okey? But what about the inputs to that function? How can I see, and understand, that `[x]` would be a valid input compatible with the type of R.chain and the rest of the *formula manipulation* we did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from this:

> chain ::      (a -> (x -> b)) -> (x -> a) -> (x -> b)

As it seems you've already understood, here we are interpreting `m b` to be "a function that takes an `x` and returns a `b`". So it follows that `m a` would be "a function that takes an `x` and returns an `a`".

Comparing this side-by-side with the signature of `concat` (I'll use `y` to avoid confusion between different `x` es):

```
(a -> (x -> b))
 y -> [y]-> [y]
```

We can see that `a` is `y`, `x` is `[y]`, and `b` is also `[y]`. So a function that takes an `x` and returns `a` would have the signature `[y] -> y`, which is precisely the signature that `head` has.

So what we have at the end is:

```
append                    head
 a ->    m b                m a              m b
 a ->  x  ->  b     ->  ( x  -> a)   ->  ( x  ->  b )
(y -> [y] -> [y])   ->  ([y] -> y)   ->  ([y] -> [y])
```

Does that help clear it up?

One other way to look at this is that if `f` and `g` are both functions, then:

```
chain(f, g)(x)  is equivalent to   f(g(x), x)
```

Which is pretty much what we see in the [Ramda source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/chain.js):

```
fn(monad(x))(x)
```

From this, we can see that functions `f` and `g` are `chain`-able when the following are both true:

- `g(x)` has the same type as the first parameter of `f`
- `f`'s second parameter has the same type as `g`'s first parameter

Comment: Thanks! You made it look so simple :)  I understand more now but I don't understand why "it follows that m a would be a function that takes an x".  All the "m" *have to* have the same type as input? I think I am confused because `m a` and `m b` have different outputs (a and b) so it is not obvious to me that the inputs should be/must be the same.

Comment: (that is x in `x -> a` and `x -> b`).

Comment: @taz0k As I understand it, the `m` in `m b` can be seen as anything involved in defining `m b` _other than_ the `b` part. So if `m b` is _"a function that takes an `x` and returns a `b`"_ then the `m` refers to the _"a function that takex an `x` and returns a ..."_ portion of that. Between `x -> a` and `x -> b`, the `x -> ` part is what they have in common (encapsulated in the `m`), and the `a` or `b` part is what differentiates them, which is why it is external to the `m`: `m a` and `m b`.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! That makes sense :)

Comment: @taz0k: A little more specifically, `m` is the `Chain` type from the definition `chain :: Chain m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`.  Each instance is parameterized by another type (`a` and `b`).  The point is that the chain in question, a *function* that takes an `x` and returns a ...",  is the *same one* throughout the signature.